# Javascript: value of radio button to empty blank square box using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, innerhtml

I'm having trouble display value of radio button
when I click on the radio buttons,
I want to see all the values of buttons in the box.
its shows values on the console but in the box, it only shows 'carrot' which is one of ingredients in the array.

```
function mixRecipeBox(){
var mixIngredients = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(i=0; i<mixIngredients.length; i++){
    if(mixIngredients[i].checked)
    console.log(mixIngredients[i].value);
    document.getElementById('mixbox').innerHTML = mixIngredients[i].value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are replacing all data of mixbox in each loop. use this to
   append data.
2. You forgot {} for **if block**
3. Empty mixbox on start of function.
4. use checkbox instead of radio so user can discard choice.

```js
    function mixRecipeBox(){
    document.getElementById('mixbox').innerHTML=""
    var currentHTML;
    var mixIngredients = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    
      for(i=0; i<mixIngredients.length; i++){
        if(mixIngredients[i].checked)
        {
         console.log(mixIngredients[i].value);
         currentHTML= document.getElementById('mixbox').innerHTML;
         document.getElementById('mixbox').innerHTML = currentHTML+mixIngredients[i].value;
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="mixRecipeBox()">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" onchange="mixRecipeBox()">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" onchange="mixRecipeBox()">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" onchange="mixRecipeBox()">
<div id="mixbox"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! it seemed work but when I clicked one button, it shows all values of buttons in the box. it's checkbox not radio button sorry

Comment: oh sorry my question was not clear enough my question was I want to show only the value that were clicked Thank you

Comment: Ok. I have update my code and description. Please read again and run code snippet to check result.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each radio element and assign a *click* event handler.

The radio button *click* handler first clears the `mixbox`, then loops over each radio element and puts checked radio button values in the `mixbox`.

```
<div id="rads">
    <input type="radio" value="one"   />1
    <input type="radio" value="two"   />2
    <input type="radio" value="three" />3
</div>
<div id="mixbox"></div>

<script>

var rads = document.querySelectorAll('#rads input[type=radio]');
var mixbox = document.getElementById('mixbox');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(rads, function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        mixbox.innerHTML = '';
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(rads, function (ele) {
            if ( ele.checked ) { mixbox.innerHTML += ele.value + '<br>'; }
        })
    })
})

</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/e4ppx8a0/)